# Hbase SingleColumnValueFilter return raw if column doesn't exists

Tags: rest, hbase, hbase-filter

I have an Hbase table which has for some rows `col1` qualifier and for the rest, it doesn't. That means that not all the rows have `col1` qualifier. I want to filter `col1` qualifier on the value `dog`.

I am using `SingleColumnValueFilter`:

```
<Scanner batch="300">
<filter>
    { 
         "type":"SingleColumnValueFilter",
         "op":"EQUAL",
         "family":"YW5pbWFs",
         "qualifier":"Y29sMQ==",
         "latestVersion":true,
         "comparator":{ 
            "type":"BinaryComparator",
            "value":"ZG9n"
         }
      }
</filter>
</Scanner>
```

I am observing a strange behaviour of `SingleColumnValueFilter` when I am getting the results. It returns not only the filtered results but also returns rows for which qualifier `col1` doesn't exist.

Has anyone faced the same problem? How it can be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ifMissing` parameter is a solution.

It seems that `SingleColumnValueFilter` by default doesn't apply a filter on rows which are a missing qualifier. Missing rows filtering can be enabled by `ifMissing` parameter.

```
<Scanner batch="300">
<filter>
    { 
         "type":"SingleColumnValueFilter",
         "op":"EQUAL",
         "family":"YW5pbWFs",
         "qualifier":"Y29sMQ==",
         "latestVersion":true,
         "ifMissing": true,
         "comparator":{ 
            "type":"BinaryComparator",
            "value":"ZG9n"
         }
      }
</filter>
</Scanner>
```